# tooltip content undefined - google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I added code for tool tip display when hovering the pointers in the google map.It is showing the tool tip but the content is "undefined". How can put the corresponding content related to the pointer into the tool tip box.The code is :

```
function initialize() {

      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.7,-95.4),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("salon_map"), myOptions);

      var locations = [
         __newmapdetls__
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var location = locations[i];
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+location[3]+"|FF0000|000000",
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));


        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: location[0],
            zIndex: location[3],
            tooltip:"testinggg"+i
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infowindow1.open(map, this);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            infowindow1.close(map, this);
        });
        var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:  "'"+this.tooltip+"'"
        });
      }
    }
```

Also url is : http://myshopsalon.com/find-a-shop-salon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content of the infowindow   `onmouseover`(you may access there the tooltip-property of the specific marker)

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow1.setContent(this.tooltip);
        infowindow1.open(map, this);
    });
```

the initializing of `infowindow1` move to outside the loop and leave the arguments empty.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setContent' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things I noticed when looking at your page source:

- Your page is loading both jQuery 1.10.1 and 1.7.2. But it isn't using `noConflict()`. So these two jQuery versions are stepping on each other.
- You're also loading *three* copies of the Maps API: two copies of version 3 *and* a copy of the deprecated version 2 API.

Now to your question:

- Use a closure to save your variables for each iteration of the marker loop. You can do this by simply calling a function in each iteration.
- Instead of using `this` when you call `infowindow.open()`, use `marker`. (`this` and `marker` may be the same in this context, but use `marker` for consistency.)
- The `.close()` method of an infowindow does not take any parameters.
- Don't set the `tooltip` property when you create the marker. That *may* work, but it isn't documented that you can add your own properties in this fashion. Instead, simply use a local variable or parameter for `tooltip`.
- I would create the infowindow before adding the event listeners. This will actually work fine in either order (since the event listeners are asynchronous), but it looks better to see the infowindow created first.

So, change your `for` loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    addMarker( locations[i], "testinggg" + i );
}

function addMarker( location, tooltip ) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+location[3]+"|FF0000|000000",
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
    );

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: location[0],
        zIndex: location[3]
    });


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:  "'" + tooltip + "'"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });
}
```

That said, you may not like the result you get when you open an infowindow in response to moving the mouse over a marker. What if the marker is near the top of the window? The page will immediately move to make the infowindow fit on the screen, and now the marker won't be under the mouse any more.

You're already setting the `title` property when you create the marker. This should cause a normal browser tooltip to appear when the mouse is hovered over the marker, and it won't cause the map to move as the infowindow may do. Any reason not to just use that tooltip instead of the infowindow? You could just remove all of the infowindow code, or let the infowindow open on a click as it normally would.

Comment: there is an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined"

Comment: Did you define the `addMarker` function as in my example?

Comment: `addmarker` or `addMarker`? My code defines and calls an `addMarker` function. Does your code have that function?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined

Comment: So where did you put the `addMarker` function?

Comment: I put the code that you give into the file and it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined"

Comment: Well, I can't see your code unless you show it to me. :-) Can you add the updated code to your question? Please keep the original code in your question for reference, and add a new section with the updated code. Post the entire new version of your `initialize` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:  "'"+marker.tooltip+"'"
});
```

**EDIETD:**

```
 var contentString = "testinggg"+i;
 var infowindow1[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     icon: image,
     title: location[0],
     zIndex: location[3],
     tooltip:"testinggg"+i
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
     infowindow1[i].open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow1[i].close(map, marker);
  });
```

You can not get the property of marker in the info window. So you need to define the content in other variable.

Comment: but it shows an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: tooltip is not defined "

Comment: @Preethy I have updated the edited code. Check it. There was the problem in the infowindow. you was using the same infowindow for each now check it again. Hope this will help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38393/discussion-between-preethy-and-broken-heart-)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'open'